# How do I use RxJava 1.x to takeUntil with paging that has to call for each page with different data?

Tags: java, rx-java

I've seen many variations on this question around SO.  However, none that quite represents my case.  I've whipped up a little test, but I'm not clear on how to proceed with the implementation of the method `getPages` below.  The strategy is to call `PageProvider#getPage(null)` on the first call, then call `PageProvider#getPage(page.next)` (where `page` is the page returned by the last call) until `page.done()` returns `true`.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Single;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

public class RxJava1TakeUntilTest {
  PageProvider provider = new PageProvider(3);

  Observable<PageProvider.Page> getPages() {
    // TODO: call provider.getPage(null) then provider.getPage(page.next) until page.done() is true
    return null;
  }

  @Test
  public void testTakeUntil() {
    getPages().subscribe(page -> System.out.println(page.toString()));
  }

  public static class PageProvider {
    public static class Page {
      public String current;
      public String next; // is null if no more pages

      public Page(String current, String next) {
        this.current = current;
        this.next = next;
      }

      public boolean done() {
        return next == null;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return current + " -> " + next;
      }
    }

    int pageCount;
    Page firstPage;
    Map<String, Page> pages = new HashMap<>();

    public PageProvider(int pageCount) {
      this.pageCount = pageCount;
      for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
        Page page = new Page(uuid(), i == pageCount - 1 ? null : uuid());
        if (i == 0) firstPage = page;
        pages.put(page.current, page);
      }
    }

    public Single<Page> getPage(String index) {
      return Single.just(index == null ? firstPage : pages.get(index));
    }

    static String uuid() {
      return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
  }
}
```

In case you want to create a quick Java project, here's a `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
  id 'java-library'
}
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
  compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.8'

  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PageProvider` is implemented incorrectly (your pages are not linked) but once you fix that you can implement paging using

```
Observable<PageProvider.Page> getPages() {
    BehaviorSubject<String> pageControl = BehaviorSubject.create((String)null);
    Observable<PageProvider.Page> ret = pageControl.asObservable()
            .concatMap(apageIndex ->
                       provider.getPage(apageIndex).toObservable().doOnNext(
                               page-> {
                                   if (page.next == null)
                                       pageControl.onCompleted();
                                   else
                                       pageControl.onNext(page.next);
                               }));
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: FYI, I fixed `PageProvider` -- thanks for pointing that out (I also added a test for `PageProvider` itself).  Your suggestion looks pretty good, although it takes a little more in-depth knowledge of RxJava.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (https://github.com/ctranxuan/howtos-rxjava/blob/master/src/main/java/org/ws13/howtos/rxjava/pagination/HowToHandlePagination.java).

One possible solution would be something like that ?

```
Flowable<Page> getPages() {
    // TODO: call provider.getPage(null) then provider.getPage(page.next) until page.done() is true
    AtomicReference<Page> ref = new AtomicReference<>();

    return Flowable.just(ref)
                   .map(AtomicReference::get) // get the current page
                   .map(page -> page.next)    // get the next index
                   .flatMapSingle(index -> provider.getPage(index)) // get the next page
                   .doOnNext(ref::set)
                   .repeatUntil(() -> ref.get() != null && ref.get().done())
                   .startWith(provider.getPage(null) // deal with 1st page
                                      .toFlowable()
                                      .doOnNext(ref::set))
                    ;
}
```

Not sure it's the best solution but I hope it helps.

Comment: That's a good looking solution, but uses RxJava 2.x's `Flowable`.  This solution requires RxJava 1.x.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I've missed that RxJava 1.x doesn't have the operator `repeatUntil()`. But this can be fixed by combining a `repeat()` with a `takeUntil()`.
Here it is:

```
 AtomicReference<Page> ref = new AtomicReference<>();

 return Observable.just(ref)
                  .map(AtomicReference::get) // get the current page
                  .map(page -> page.next)    // get the next index
                  .flatMapSingle(index -> provider.getPage(index)) // get the next page
                  .doOnNext(ref::set)
                  .repeat()
                  .takeUntil(Page::done)
                  .startWith(provider.getPage(null) // deal with 1st page
                                     .toObservable()
                                     .doOnNext(ref::set))
            ;
```

Comment: This is a slight & probably better variation on my solution, but I think @JohnWowUs's solution is superior to both of ours since it doesn't involve `AtomicReference`.

Comment: Yes, not sure the impact about the `AtomicReference` within the Rx flow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do, is to let your PageProvider implement `Iterable` and return an `Iterator<Page>` that goes through the pages in order. Once you have that, you can simply do `Observable.from(pageProvider)`. The advantage here is that you can also use Java's native `forEach` if you want to.

Alternatively you can work with `Observable.create` and push your items into it one by one using `onNext` and finally calling `onComplete`.

Finally, if you don't care about order, or you change your `Map` to an ordered one, you can simply do `Observable.from(map.values())`.

Comment: No can do.  In my production code, I have no control over the code that `PageProvider` represents.  :)

Answer (score 0):

*NB: while this is an answer, I'm not convinced that it's the best.*

Here's how I solved it (*all* code, including a new test to ensure `PageProvider` is working correctly).  It's similar to @ctranxuan's answer.  I'm definitely open to improvement suggestions.  The part I'm not wild about is the potential performance impact of using `AtomicReference` `get()` & `set(..)`.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Single;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;

public class RxJava1TakeUntilTest {

  @Test
  public void testCountNumberOfPages() {
    int count = 3;
    PageProvider provider = new PageProvider(count);
    AtomicReference<PageProvider.Page> holder = new AtomicReference<>(null);

    Observable.just(holder) // reference to holder of current page
        .repeat() // repeat forever
        .flatMapSingle( // get a page
            it -> {
              PageProvider.Page page = it.get();
              return provider.getPage(page == null ? null : page.next);
            })
        .map( // update holder to latest response
            page -> {
              holder.set(page);
              return page;
            })
        .takeUntil(page -> page.done())
        .reduce(0, (total, page) -> total + 1)
        .test()
        .assertResult(count);
  }

  @Test
  public void testPageProvider() {
    PageProvider provider = new PageProvider(2);
    provider
        .getPage(null)
        .map(
            page -> {
              assertNotNull(page);
              assertNotNull(page.current);
              assertNotNull(page.next);
              return page.next;
            })
        .flatMap(provider::getPage)
        .map(
            page -> {
              assertNotNull(page);
              assertNotNull(page.current);
              assertNull(page.next);
              return page;
            })
        .test()
        .assertNoErrors();
  }

  public static class PageProvider {
    int pageCount;
    Page firstPage;
    Map<String, Page> pages = new HashMap<>();

    public PageProvider(int pageCount) {
      this.pageCount = pageCount;
      String next = uuid();
      for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
        Page page = new Page(next, i == pageCount - 1 ? null : uuid());
        if (i == 0) firstPage = page;
        pages.put(page.current, page);
        next = page.next;
      }
    }

    public Single<Page> getPage(String index) {
      return Single.just(index == null ? firstPage : pages.get(index));
    }

    static String uuid() {
      return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public static class Page {
      public String current;
      public String next; // is null if no more pages

      public Page(String current, String next) {
        this.current = current;
        this.next = next;
      }

      public boolean done() {
        return next == null;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return current + " -> " + next;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think @johnwowus's answer is the best, since it doesn't involve `AtomicReference`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to use `Observable.create()`:

```
Observable<Page> getPages() {
   AsyncOnSubscribe<Page, Page> stateful =
       AsyncOnSubscribe.createStateful(() -> provider.getPageFrom(null),
                                       (page, requested, observer) -> {
                                             if (!page.done()) {
                                                 observer.onNext(Observable.just(page));
                                             }
                                             return provider.getPageFrom(page.next);
                                      });
    return Observable.create(stateful);
}
...
public static class PageProvider {
    public Page getPageFrom(String index) {
        return index == null ? firstPage : pages.get(index);
    }
}
```

... provided a slightly change in the `PageProvider`.
But in this case, you have some `Observable.just()` being created (as many as there are pages).